# NoSql TO mysql Database convertion

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, nosql

Is there is any simple procedure for converting google's nosql to local mysql database ? 
I have downloaded all the data using [Remote API Bulk Loader](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata) .
How can i seperate desired entity from this bulk data .
Later i want to convert all entities to mysql databse.

Comment: If by procedure you mean a linear process, or a one size fits all answer, no. Especially not a simple one.

Comment: Will you please give me brief description , what i do ?

Comment: Well, first, what have you tried? I guess a good starting point would be to start out by designing your data schema. That should not be very difficult. Once that's in place, you can copy the data over in one of a million different ways.

Comment: I have downloaded all the entities using `appcfg.py` command.

Comment: Used Remote API Bulk Loader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First downloaded all the data in CSV format using following command ,

`appcfg.py download_data --config_file=bulkloader.yaml --filename=users.csv --kind=Permission --url=http://your_app_id.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api`

Then used **phpmyadmin**.